# Error accessing the database DSN

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with logging a Support user into an Application that has a SQL Server backend.

When configuring the application itself, the SQL set-up asked me to assign whether the Security to access the Application would be Windows Authentication or SQL: server Authentication, I chose Windows Authentication, and as I was using a login called 
'LabUser1' I have been able to login to the application fine.

However, when I logon to the server using a different windows login, this time 'Support', SQL keeps giving me the error:

> Error accessing the database DSN

Now I know the reason is because the install of SQL happened using the 'Labuser1' profile, but how can I create a script that will allow me to add the 'Support' user to the 'Allowed Logins' so that I can logon to the app server and at least open the Application? (I have seperate logins for when I see the applicatiojn login window, so please don't confuse the matter by thinking it is a simple case of creating a login for Support....I am talking about logging into the server)

The current batch file I am trying to run is:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\OCDBB01  -i createSupportlogin.sql
```

Then I run this batch file after having created the following SQL script:

```
CREATE LOGIN OCDMW1\Support FROM WINDOWS
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the situation is a bit confusing to me however it appears that the "SQL setup" that is part of the application configuration created a ODBC DSN that uses the credentials of person logging into the machine as the login for SQL Server.

Simply creating a new (correct) login to the SQL instance may not resolve this issue since that does nothing to modify the DSN.  If you are tied to using Window Authentication for SQL access it might be necessary to create multiple DSNs for the application to use and find a way to have the correct DSN associated to the right login for the application to use.